# Angular Material Icons won't work when icon-property is filled from scope

Tags: angularjs, icons, angular-material

i'm having an issue concerning the Angular Material Icons I cloned from [github here](https://klarsys.github.io/angular-material-icons/). When I use the `ng-md-icon` directive and specify the icon somehow like `icon="cancel"` it works as expected. As soon as I try to fill it from scope like `icon="{{myIconSet.dialogButtonCancel}}` (which also points to "cancel") the questionmark-icon shows up. When looking at the html in chrome's dev console, both icon-propertys show `icon="cancel"`. Below I included the code, resulting html from dev-console and the rendered result. I can not provide a plunker since I am not (!) able to reproduce this behaviour.
I was looking around the web for quite some time and tried lots of things other ppl advised to do in somewhat similar cases (different browsers and icons, changing the order of loading .js-files in my html, loading above/below fold, changing the order of injecting modules into the app..) - yet nothing did the trick.
I'm using angular, uibootstrap, bootstrap notify and jquery.

Code snippet:

```
        <div id="dialogButtonEndApp" class="dialogButton materialIconShadow" style="float:left">
            <ng-md-icon icon="cancel" style="fill: black" size="60"></ng-md-icon>
        </div>

        <div id="dialogButtonCancel" class="dialogButton materialIconShadow activeButton" style="float:right">
            <ng-md-icon icon="{{myIconSet.dialogButtonCancel}}" style="fill: white" size="60"></ng-md-icon>
        </div>
```

Resulting Html document:

```
<div class="dialogButtonArea">

        <div id="dialogButtonEndApp" class="dialogButton" style="float:left">
            <ng-md-icon icon="cancel" style="fill: black" size="60"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="60" height="60"><path d="M12 2C6.47 2 2 6.47 2 12s4.47 10 10 10 10-4.47 10-10S17.53 2 12 2zm5 13.59L15.59 17 12 13.41 8.41 17 7 15.59 10.59 12 7 8.41 8.41 7 12 10.59 15.59 7 17 8.41 13.41 12 17 15.59z"></path></svg></ng-md-icon>
        </div>

        <div id="dialogButtonCancel" class="dialogButton materialIconShadow activeButton" style="float:right">
            <ng-md-icon icon="cancel" style="fill: white" size="60"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="60" height="60"><path d="M12 2C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm1 17h-2v-2h2v2zm2.07-7.75l-.9.92C13.45 12.9 13 13.5 13 15h-2v-.5c0-1.1.45-2.1 1.17-2.83l1.24-1.26c.37-.36.59-.86.59-1.41 0-1.1-.9-2-2-2s-2 .9-2 2H8c0-2.21 1.79-4 4-4s4 1.79 4 4c0 .88-.36 1.68-.93 2.25z"></path></svg></ng-md-icon>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[And the rendered result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8egY.png)

Does anyone have a clue what's going on here? I'm thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The owner of the repo is using `attire.$observe('icon', replace);` and is using the question mark as a default when the icon is not found.

Said that the problem is using the icon attribute with an interpolation ({{}}), the first time is using {{myIconSet.dialogButtonCancel}} as an icon and because it not a valid one, it uses the question marks. But once the expression is evaluated it should be updating to the new one, as you see the html saying cancel.

I would go to the `replace` function inside the directive code and check if it's firing or not and with what value.

If you are using it inside another directive, make a test putting the icon in other place, and see what happens. You can always change the icon attribute manually.

Comment: You were right. The icon library contains a check against undefined, that prevents the $observe to work. The problem seems to be that angular is evaluating and replacing the {{..}}-expression to slow, the icon lib finds an undefined value inside the icon-property, thus not usin an observe on these variables.

Comment: It might be related with priorities of directives if you are using it inside a directive.